# Dynamically hiding/showing the output

Tags: output-formatting

Consider some reference table:

```
table=Table[i,{i,1,100,1}]
```

Is there any way to dynamically hide/show the output without placing `table` in a separate section (and contracting it), and (obviously) without adding `;`? For instance, something like a clickable spoiler (but again, not the section)?

Comment: Maybe `OpenerView` ?

Comment: Ctrl+', tutorial/KeyboardShortcutListing